# Django changing image path while saving

Tags: django, image, django-models

I have a system where users can upload cover photos to playlists. The playlist model is as following:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    .
    .
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/playlistimages')
    .
    .
```

The upload mechanism is as follows: Users chooses a photo, I upload it to a temporary model, and show it to the user. If the user chooses to save the photo, I proceed and save the image. Preview images are kept in a different model

```
class PreviewImage(models.Model):
    .
    .
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/previewimages')
    .
    .
```

Not to upload the image twice, when the user first chooses the photo, I upload it and save in the preview image model. Then, if the user proceeds to save the playlist, I only send the preview image id to the server and save the image in that object to the playlist as follows:

```
playlist.image = previewImage.image
playlist.save()
```

The problem is, the image is at first uploaded to the previewimages folder, and when I save the playlist's image as in the example above, it is still in that folder. How can I move this file to playlistimages folder while saving?

Comment: Better solution is to keep one model with `image_type` (IntegerField + choices). You know... you can create one model i.e. StoreImage and have one upload dir :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing what you want, you can overwrite the PlayList form's 'save' method. Something like:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    temp_file_id = self.cleaned_data.get('preview_image_id', False)
    if temp_file_id:
       try:
           temp_file = PreviewImage.objects.get(pk=temp_file_id)
           instance = super(PlayListForm, self).save(commit)
           instance.image.save(
               os.path.basename(temp_file.file.path), 
               temp_file.file.file, 
               commit
           )

           # If you want to erase the file from its previous location, 
           # as well as the PreviewImage object do the following
           os.remove(temp_file.file.path)
           temp_file.delete()

           # Finally return saved instance
           return instance
        except PreviewImage.DoesNotExist:
            # handle this the way it fits your needs...
        except Exception as e:
            raise e;
    else:
        # handle this the way it fits your needs...
```

This code is untested, it is only meant as a general idea.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have used a similar approach finally, the only difference is as I've been storing images in Amazon's S3 service, I needed to save the image in a buffer and push it to S3

Comment: if anyone just want to copy one model's uploaded image to another then this should be enough : `new_model.image_field.save(os.path.basename(old_model.file_field.path),
                                         old_model.file_field.file.file)`